# .NET assembly version number

Tags: .net, .net-core, version, versioning

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version) of .NET API says that full version number consist of four parts:

**major**.**minor**.**build**.**revision**, where

> **Build**: A difference in build number represents a recompilation of the same source. Different build numbers might be used when the processor, platform, or compiler changes.
>
> **Revision**: Assemblies with the same name, major, and minor version numbers but different revisions are intended to be fully interchangeable. A higher revision number might be used in a build that fixes a security hole in a previously released assembly.

So, it seems the **revision** corresponds to **PATCH** version in terms of [Semantic Versioning 2.0.0](https://semver.org/), and **build** is mapped to [**build metadata**](https://semver.org/#spec-item-10). And, thus, version 1.2.`x`.4 is later then 1.2.`y`.3 because they have same **major** and **minor** numbers but 1.2.`x`.4 *fixes a security hole in a previously released assembly*.

But thе statement is not true in case of ClickOnce deployment. The following steps will be completed successfully:

1. Create an empty Windows Forms application using Visual Studio.
2. Go to **Publish** tab in project properties and specify publishing folder location.
3. Set version number to `1.2.3.4`.
4. Click on the **Publish Now** button.
5. Change version to `1.2.4.3`.
6. Click on the **Publish Now** button.

But if you swap steps 3 and 5, it reproduces the following warning:

> Published version 1.2.4.3 will be replaced by an older version (1.2.3.4).

Thus, if **build** values of version numbers are different, then **revision** values are ignored. Moreover, it predicates the version 1.2.4.3 is newer than 1.2.3.4.

Documentation of `Version.CompareTo` method confirm such behavior:

> The components of `Version` in decreasing order of importance are: major, minor, build, and revision.

But if I rebuild old hotfix commit that **major** and **minor** equal to the same parts of latest version, what would it be? CI/CD builds counter value will be increased. So, the latest version will be "older" than latest build.

Another example is using of modulo for CI/CD builds counter to [limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute) **build** value. After `UInt16.MaxValue-1` the counter will be "reset" to `0`. So, if **major** and **minor** were not changed, it will produce a version that is "older" than previous.

So, I feel the doubt whether I should use the version number format that is specified in documentation. What are possible consequences of using **major**.**minor**.**revision**.**build** instead? Is it possible to ask Microsoft for documentation review?

Comment: From [`Version.CompareTo` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version.compareto?view=netframework-4.8#System_Version_CompareTo_System_Object_): "**Remarks** The components of Version in decreasing order of importance are: major, minor, build, and revision. An unknown component is assumed to be older than any known component." Examples follow the quoted text on the cited page.

Comment: @HABO , thanks. Your comment is very helpful. I will update my answer some later with accordance the information.

Comment: You can also check the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/version.cs,84ebd6f1d2bcfe63) for `Version.CompareTo`. It's pretty straightforward.

Comment: "And, thus, version 1.2.x.4 is later then 1.2.y.3" is wrong and leads to all the rest misunderstanding. You can only say 1.2.x.4 is newer than 1.2.x.3.

Comment: @LexLi, documentation says: "A difference in *build* number represents a recompilation of the *same source*". So, if definitions of **build** and **revision** from the documentation are correct, then version with higher **revision** should be newer independent of **build** value. That's the point!